# Int32 cast error in Generic Inquiry after saving a row in the table

Tags: acumatica

I created a new custom table, and a new screen (FormView) to enter data. I created a Generic Inquiry to navigate to the new entry screen.  After I entered and save the first record in the new table with the new entry screen, the Generic Inquiry screen throws a casting error on one of the columns. This should all be very quick and easy, but I can't seem to get around the casting error.

New table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DPItemRebate](
   [CompanyID] [int] NOT NULL,
   [VendorID] [int] NOT NULL,
   [CustomerID] [int] NOT NULL,
   [InventoryID] [int] NOT NULL,
   [RebateAmt] [decimal](19, 4) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_DPItemRebate] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    ([CompanyID] ASC, [VendorID] ASC, [CustomerID] ASC, [InventoryID] ASC)...
```

DAC:

```
[Serializable]
public class DPItemRebate : IBqlTable
{
   #region VendorID
   [PXDBInt(IsKey = true)]
   [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Vendor")]
   [Vendor(typeof(Search<BAccountR.bAccountID,
       Where<BAccountR.type, Equal<BAccountType.companyType>, 
          Or<Vendor.type, NotEqual<BAccountType.employeeType>>>>), 
       Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible, CacheGlobal = true, 
       Filterable = true)]
   [PXRestrictor(typeof(Where<Vendor.status, IsNull, 
       Or<Vendor.status, Equal<BAccount.status.active>, 
       Or<Vendor.status, Equal<BAccount.status.oneTime>>>>), 
       PX.Objects.AP.Messages.VendorIsInStatus, typeof(Vendor.status))]
   public virtual int? VendorID { get; set; }
   public abstract class vendorID : IBqlField { }
   #endregion

   #region CustomerID
   [PXDBInt(IsKey = true)]
   [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Customer")]
   [CustomerActive(typeof(Search<BAccountR.bAccountID,
       Where<Customer.type, IsNotNull, 
           Or<BAccountR.type, Equal<BAccountType.companyType>>>>), 
       Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible, 
       DescriptionField = typeof(Customer.acctName), 
       Filterable = true)]
   public virtual int? CustomerID { get; set; }
   public abstract class customerID : IBqlField { }
   #endregion

   #region InventoryID
   [PXDBInt(IsKey = true)]
   [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Inventory Item")]
   [Inventory(typeof(Search<InventoryItem.inventoryID, 
       Where2<Match<Current<AccessInfo.userName>>, 
           And<InventoryItem.itemStatus, NotEqual<InventoryItemStatus.unknown>>>>), 
       typeof(InventoryItem.inventoryCD), typeof(InventoryItem.descr), 
       Filterable = true)]
   public virtual int? InventoryID { get; set; }
   public abstract class inventoryID : IBqlField { }
   #endregion

   #region RebateAmt
   [PXDBDecimal()]
   [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Rebate Amount")]
   public virtual Decimal? RebateAmt { get; set; }
   public abstract class rebateAmt : IBqlField { }
   #endregion
}
```

Generic Inquiry:

```
   Tables: DPItemRebate.DPItemRebate
   Relations: <none>
   Results: 
       Object: DPItemRebate
       Data Fields: vendorID, vendorID_description, customerID, customerID_description, inventoryID, inventoryID_description, rebateAmt
```

The DAC fields are lookups except for RebateAmt. I borrowed the selector attributes from elsewhere in Acumatica DAC code. I added all fields to a new entry page, entered data with the new page, then open the Generic Inquiry and it gives an error:

```
"[InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.]
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Int32() +65
 PX.Data.PXDataRecord.GetInt32(Int32 i) +96
 PX.Data.PXDBIntAttribute.RowSelecting(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectingEventArgs e) +210
 PX.Data.PXCache.OnRowSelecting(Object item, PXDataRecord record, Int32& position, Boolean isReadOnly) +650"
```

and

```
"[PXException: Error: An error occurred during processing of the field Customer: Specified cast is not valid..]"
```

When I comment out the DAC lookup definitions for Vendor, CustomerActive, And Inventory; the casting error goes away, so it's likely related; but I need these for field lookups. What am I defining wrong?

Comment: Have you investigated the SQL trace, to see what is passed to the database?  Also change the CustomerActive attribute, to a generic search.  That will help determine if that attribute causes the problem.  Also change the DescriptionField property to BAccountR.acctName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed all of my lookup field attribute definitions to base PXSelector attributes and it finally worked without error. I still don't know why the other Acumatica ones threw errors, though.

Answer (score 0):

Do not redeclare `[PXDBInt(IsKey = true)]` it is already defined in the `[CustomerActive]` attribute.